# Flutter Text Field allowed text format

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have two text fields, one of them should be year so I want to allow only enter numbers between 1900 and 2020, second one for ratings and it should be 9.9 at most and it can be 5 or 5.5 etc, 
When I use below code, I can get 1800 or 3450 in year field and rating side can be 123 or anything has 3 digits. Is there any way to restrict them as just like I want?

For years;

```
new TextField(
                          controller: _disControllerF,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: new TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              fontFamily: "SegoeUI",
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                              fontSize: 16.0
                          ),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          inputFormatters:<TextInputFormatter>[
                            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(4),
                            WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                          ],
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                            ),
                            hintText: '1900',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                fontFamily: "SegoeUI",
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                fontSize: 16.0),
                            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets
                                .symmetric(
                                horizontal: 10.0),
                          ),),
```

For ratings;

```
new TextField(
                  controller: _disControllerR,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontFamily: "SegoeUI",
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                      fontSize: 16.0
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  inputFormatters:<TextInputFormatter>[
                    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3),
                    WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[1-9.]")),
                  ],
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                    ),
                    hintText: '6.5',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        fontFamily: "SegoeUI",
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                        fontSize: 16.0),
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets
                        .symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10.0),
                  ),),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Form** widget and **TextFormField** so that you can **validator** in you TextFormField and add your condition inside. using key parameter in Form you can validate with the Button click.

```
var formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

Form(
        key: formkey,
        child: Column(children: [
          TextFormField(
            //controller: _disControllerF,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: new TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                fontFamily: "SegoeUI",
                fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                fontSize: 16.0),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(4),
              WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
            ],
            validator: (value) {
              String errorString;
              if (int.parse(value) < 2200 && int.parse(value) > 1800) {
              } else {
                errorString = "Enter value between 1800 and 220";
              }
              return errorString;
            },

            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: new OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: '1900',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  fontFamily: "SegoeUI",
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                  fontSize: 16.0),
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
            ),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            //controller: _disControllerR,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: new TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                fontFamily: "SegoeUI",
                fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                fontSize: 16.0),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3),
              WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[1-9.]")),
            ],
            validator: (value) {
              String errorString;
              if (double.parse(value) > 9.9 || double.parse(value) < 5) {
                errorString = "Enter inbetween 5 to 9.9";
              }
              return errorString;
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: new OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: '6.5',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  fontFamily: "SegoeUI",
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                  fontSize: 16.0),
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
            ),
          ),
          RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
            if (formkey.currentState.validate()) {}
          })
        ]))
```

Comment: Thanks. I though to use validator before but I can't be sure how can I use each data from validator, because I am using this data to make an api resquest url and using them like that "&rating=${_disControllerR.text}&firstyear=${_disControllerF.text}&lastyear=${_disControllerL.text}"

Comment: ok I figured out I need to use onSaved to name each textformfield, it is all good now, thanks a lot.